# What is contained in this table of 8-bit and 16-bit encodings?

Tags: binary, unsigned-integer

I am trying to read a file which contains 8-bit unsigned integer values. In the [file description](http://www.color.org/icc33.pdf) document, Table 70 (below) describes how you get from the 8-bit value to the desired value (known as a* or b*). But I can't figure out what's in the 2nd column under "8 bit". What is 00h, 80h, or FFh? Is this some kind of code? From [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/lab2uint8.html) it looks like they are numbers: 0, 128, and 255, but what is their format in the table?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I know a little more: The values are hexadecimals (base 16), and can be converted to decimals [here](http://codebeautify.org/hex-decimal-converter). Some background [here](http://electronics-tutorials.ws/binary/bin_3.html) if, like me, you are unfamiliar with them. I will add that this is related to reading in L* a* b* values from [CIELab format Tiff files](http://www.color.org/icc33.pdf), in case this helps someone else trying to do this.